# Mac Automator - When given a folder containing many files with the same name format, organise the folder with new sub-folders

Tags: finder, automator, script, folders

So I have a folder which contains many .mp3 and .cdg files (setting up a Karaoke system )

All of the files follow the same naming system:

`Artist` - `Song name` [Karaoke]

Rather than having all of the files together, I would like to separate them by `Artist` sub-folders.

E.g. a new folder called 'Trisha & Don Henley Yearwood' should be created and then all files that contain that `Artist` title in their file name before the hyphen `-` should be moved to that folder.

If someone who has written a script or automation process like this before could help, it would be much appreciated.

I haven't been able to find any scripts online that answer this exact use case.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for any  scripts anywhere?